# Why does the review audit mention "Voting to close" for an answer?

Tags: bug, review, answers, vote-to-close, review-audits

I just passed a review audit in the First Posts review. I passed it on an "I'm having this problem too" answer by downvoting it. Where it says that I passed the audit, it lists a few appropriate actions, among those actions is voting to close:

[image]

The strange thing is that this is an answer and, of course, answers can't be closed. I guess that this is because the same text is used for passed review audits on both questions and answers, but in this case it doesn't make any sense. I therefore think that it would be better to show a different message for answers and only show the current one for questions. It would be possible to use the same message for passed review audits on answers in First posts as the one for passed review audits in Late Answers, since, if my memory is correct, the one in Late Answers is the same except that it doesn't mention voting to close.

I therefore think that the "voting to close" should be removed from the message for passed review audits on answers, as voting to close an answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well,  the "audit passed" message is global as far as I know, not specific to each type of review.

Comment: The fact that downvoting a NAA is a pass seems a bit stupid to me, you should *have* to flag.

Comment: @Cai What I usually do about answers like that is that first I downvote them and then I flag them. So making a downvote fail the audit just like that wouldn't be such a good idea if the user was planning on flagging it after downvoting. Making a downvote and then "I'm done" without anything else done fail the audit would make a bit more sense, but I don't think I would be in favor of that  either.

Comment: @Cai downvoting is still a useful action as it helps non-answers become eligible for deletion sooner and it also helps get the word out to others that those answers are not useful.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or something, since

- the Audit message isn't specific to questions and answers. The actions described should cover both.
- The message says *. . .  flagging as "very low quality", **or** voting to close . . .* so the grammar is right and it doesn't imply that you must close vote to pass, but that close-voting is one of the actions that might lead to passing the audit.